# Issue with RXJS Observables making REST calls?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-services, angular2-observables

I've got an Angular 2 application which I'm connecting to a RESTful back end. Back end works fine. The Angular 2 app worked fine while I was using it with local storage. Now I'm stuck on observables.

The main component calls a service on initialization:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.appList = this.appListService.getAppList();
}
```

The appListService calls a storage service with a GET request:

```
getAppList() {
  console.log(this.storage.get());
  return this.storage.get();
```

}

The storage service hits up the back end with a get request via an endpoint:

```
get(): Observable<Course[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.BaseUrl)
                    .map(this.extractData)
                    .catch(this.handleError);
                    }
```

What all of that gets me according to the console log is this:

```
Observable_isScalar: falseoperator: CatchOperatorsource: Observable__proto__: Object
```

So how can I turn the observable into an array of objects, which is what the GET request should be bringing back from the back end?

Comment: There is no better place then the docs: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to subscribe to the observable.

```
    this.storage.get().subscribe((data: any) => {          
               console.log(data); 
    },
    error => {
               // handle the error
            });
```

Comment: I'm getting errors that suggest that it wants error handling. Something like this, perhaps? 

    getAppList() {
      this.storage.get().subscribe((data: any) => {          
           console.log(data);
           return (data);
      }, error => {console.log(error)});
  }

Comment: The above seems to work but I'm getting CORS errors. If it's ok with you, I'd like to fix those and test that it works before accepting the answer.

Comment: The CORS error will be a server side thing, the api will have to allow for other domains to call it. That isn't related to the Angular part.

Comment: CORS errors fixed. 

Your suggested answer throws me an error-it says that it wants a comma instead of the final curly bracket.

This doesn't throw an error:

`getAppList() {
      this.storage.get().subscribe((data: any) => {          
           console.log(data.toString());
           return (data);
      }, error => {console.log(error)});
  }`

But it gives me an object which JSON.stringify() doesn't work on. Neither does its toString() method.

Comment: Given that the original question was regarding the subscription I think you can mark this as answered. The second question you asked was on error handling which has also been answered. I think your latest problem is due to the data that is returned from the api. Is it valid? What does it look like if you print it to the console. You could need use JSON.parse(data); Stringify turns an object into a string, you want the other way around.

Comment: Thanks, Ben, sorry about the delay. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: Btw, things advanced a bit and broke again: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41935722/angular-2-ngfor-and-form-submit-ceased-working-when-moved-to-observables